# (ASP.NET) Automatic way to put all code-behind classes in a namespace

Tags: asp.net, namespaces

I just converted a WebSite to a Web application and put in a new namespace.

I now need to put all code behind files in this namespace.

is there an automatic way to do it or am I going to have to go to each page and do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to do it manually. ReSharper helps, although it's somewhat weak when it comes to ASP.NET, and you could use the trial version for a one-time conversion. It's a tedious chore best saved for a Friday afternoon.

Comment: or Friday at 10pm since my computer at work is so freaking slow lol

They must have thought I was kidding when I said, "Alienware will work".  They asked what kind of computer I'd need.

Comment: If I've learned anything about Visual Studio solutions it's that fixing those 400 errors will allow one project to build; that will then expose 600 errors in another project. Sorry.

Comment: I have done this manually before. If there's an automatic solution,I can't wait to hear about it.